# How to terminate terminal that is connected to a AWS box but still leave process on?

Tags: linux, macos, amazon-web-services, terminal

I have ssh'd into a ubuntu AWS box via terminal on mac. I have successfully setup the process I want to run in the box.

How do can exit out of terminal without killing the process running?

Thank you in advance.

P.S

New to linux and terminal on mac

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I use [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) to get in/out of the system while keeping the processes running.

```
$ sudo apt install screen
```

To create a new screen:

```
$ screen -S screen_name
```

Then do something in your `screen`, for example running a program, editing files, downloading file with wget, etc.

Later if you want to exit the terminal without killing the running process, simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.
The process will kept running in the background inside the `screen`

To reconnect to the screen:

```
$ screen -R screen_name
```